# Adding node edit links to a views block display?

Tags: views, 6

I have a View with a Block display which shows 4 nodes of 1 type. I'd like to add node/xx/edit links to each node on the block. I've searched Google only to get confused more. Which hook to use? views_pre_execute, views_pre_render, views_pre_view .... And once you get the right hook, how do you actually add those links? Obviously I'd like to check the current user's `node_access` permissions too before adding those links.

This is Views 2 with Drupal 6.

Comment: are you using the views ui to create the view or is it done completely through program?

Comment: Used views_ui but the view will be exported via features module in the near future.

Comment: there is a  fields called node edit link have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it. It works. I'll accept as answer if you type it as answer. I'm still however quite interested how to do this kind of thing through coding and hooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a field called Node :Edit link which can be added to the fields and it will give you the edit link. This also respects the permissions that is it would only be shown to those who have permission to edit a post.